# Android Facebook wall posting

Tags: java, android, facebook

There is the following code:

```
    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
            .setLink("some url")
            .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

It code works for me, all is good. But there is the following problem: if native Facebook app doesn't exist on the device, than this my code throws an exception. How can I fix it? Is it possible to post through browser or I must disable ability to post on the wall if user doesn't have Facebook app installed?

**Exception**:

```
 com.facebook.FacebookException: Unable to create Intent; this likely means the Facebook app is not installed.
```

Comment: you need the native facebook app AFAIK. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: which exception are you getting? can you post logcat?

Answer (score 0):

There's a canPresentShareDialog method in FacebookDialog, you should check that before creating and presenting a FacebookDialog. The canPresent method will check for the presence of the Facebook app as well as the version of the app (to make sure that it's compatible).

If canPresentShareDialog fails, then you can use the WebDialog class to present a webview version of the share dialog (it's called Feed Dialog).